# How to increment value of json variable in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I have a Loop controller and inside i have a http request and payload .
PayloadBody Looks like below.

```
{
"id"="12345"
}
```

In the counter if i have 3 it should be 12346,12347
I need to increase value of a variable each time when iterates.
i used the below JSR223 script as below

```
int counter=(vars.get('ContactId') as int) +1
vars.put('counter',counter as String)
log.info(vars.get('counter'))
```

it's taking next digit but same value in the counter it's not increasing as +1.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is changing your `12345` part to [__intSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) and [__counter()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) functions combination, i.e. something like:

```
{
"id"="${__intSum(12345,${__counter(,)},)}"
}
```

This way you will get an incremented number each time the request is sent

[image]

More information: [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test)

Comment: Thanks for the above solution. I'm trying with Aplhanumeric incremet like BA1234,BA1235 ..etc .inside a same loop. it's not accepting.I tried with the counter placing a reference variable. but no luck